# show words in paragraph even after slicing some words

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

php code to show the paragraph of text

```
<p class="feed-text" style="word-wrap:break-word;">
  <?php echo nl2br($feed->feed_text); ?>
</p>
```

Javascript code to slice text after 250 character,

```
$(function(){

    var minimized_elements = $('p.feed-text');
    minimized_elements.each(function(){    
        var t = $(this).text();        
        if(t.length < 250) return;

        $(this).html(
            t.slice(0,250)+'<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">More</a>'+
            '<span style="display:none;">'+ t.slice(250,t.length)+' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a></span>'
            );

    }); 

    $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide().prev().hide();
        $(this).next().show();        
    });

    $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();    
    });

});
```

Problem i am facing now:

```
Ten little monkeys jumping on the bed . . . and tripping over teddy bears, 
slipping on banana peels, and falling off the dock!
Those naughty monkeys sure love to monkey around!
But just WHO is causing all this monkey business? 
Try fi... More
```

Actually i entered the paragraph as like this,

```
Ten little monkeys jumping on the bed . . . 
and tripping over teddy bears, slipping on banana peels,
and falling off the dock!Those naughty monkeys sure love to monkey around! 

But just WHO is causing all this monkey business? 
Try finding the naughtiest monkey in every 
scene--and watch as she gets her comeuppance at the end!

A classic monkey rhyme with delicious illustrations,
this is sure to be a favorite on every little monkey's bookshelf.
```

I need the output like this,

```
Ten little monkeys jumping on the bed . . .
and tripping over teddy bears, slipping on banana peels,
and falling off the dock!Those naughty monkeys sure love to monkey around!

But just WHO is causing all this monkey business? Try f...More
```

Script is slicing and showing the text correctly.Since i am using this script to slice the text by 250 character and placing a `more` and `less` option,if any sentence entered in paragraph,now it is not shown as paragraph.Instead of displaying as paragraph,it is showing continuously with out any indentation. I need to show the text in paragraph,if user entered as paragraph even with `more` or `less` option using my script.

I think their is a problem in script,not able to find it,need help to solve this.

Comment: Try word-wrap:break-all?

Comment: @user1708762 tried word-wrap:break-all not working.

Comment: Then I am not sure about it. You can try using 'substring' or something instead of 'slice'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `.text()` to read the string you want to work with. Since `.text()` only delivers the plain text without any markup, you are losing the `<br>` elements that `nl2br` generates.

The first, most obvious solution would be: Why aren't you splitting the text up server-side instead of using JavaScript? That way you could apply `nl2br` separately to both parts of the text.

A Javascript solution would be to use `.html()` instead, however this is dangerous, since your splitting may happen in the middle of the `<br>` tag having you create broken HTML such as:

```
Example<b<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">More</a><span style="display:none;">r> More Text</span>
```

The proper JavaScript solution would be to loop over the children of your `.feed-text` elements including the text nodes (available in jQuery using [.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)) summing up the number of characters to find the right place to split the text.